# Cannot receive messages wrong context connectionid

Tags: asp.net, signalr

So I was using SignalR version .5 and everything was working fine. But trying to upgrade to version 1 to use the connectionSlow method. Unfortunately it seems to have broken when I have upgraded. I have an mvc application, and I am trying to use signalr to push data to the client. I want the connection to be open forever.

The server will not send messages to the client. After some investigations using a LoggingPiplineModule i found that the context.Connection.Identifier is not the connextionID of the connected browser, its asif it is trying to send it to someone else.

My Hub only has a few methods:

```
public void JoinGroup(string groupID)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.User.Identity.Name) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupID)))
        {
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupID.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            LoggerSingleton.Instance.Logger.Error("Error: Could not join group as user is not logged in or group is null");
        }
    }

    public void LeaveGroup(string groupID)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.User.Identity.Name) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupID)))
        {
            Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, groupID.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            LoggerSingleton.Instance.Logger.Error("Error: Could not leave group as user is not logged in or group is null");
        }
    }
    public static void SendCallLog(CallLog newCall, int groupID)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CommandCentreHub>();
        context.Clients.Group(groupID.ToString()).addMessage(CallLog.ToJson(newCall), groupID.ToString());
    }
```

And my javascript:

```
conChat = $.connection.commandcentrehub;

// Push method for signalR, process the pushed message passed from the server
conChat.addMessage = function (message, groupID) {
    var call = JSON.parse(message);
    updateTableImages($('#groupContent' + groupID), call, groupID);
    updateTableImages($('#groupContent' + 'All'), call, 'All');

    applyFilter();
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $('.groupID').each(function () {
    conChat.server.joinGroup(this.id.replace("group", ""));
});
});
```

And my global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new LoggingPipelineModule());

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
```

I get no errors in chrome dev, and joingroup is working properly but when the server calls addMessage I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed the issue.
It was with my javascript.

The below:

```
conChat.addMessage = function (message, groupID) { ...
```

should be:

```
conChat.client.addMessage = function (message, groupID) {
```

Hope this helps someone...